# Symfony Call to a member function setFirstname() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine, entity

I am trying to create rows in a table using a service. But it says Call to a member function setFirstname() on a non-object, which is line:
`$this->idm->setPersno($science->getPersno());`

I searched hours on google and can't find the solution to that problem. Can anybody help me?

```
$scienceList = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyTable1')->findAll();
            foreach ($scienceList as $science) 
            {
                $idm = new Users();
                $this->idm = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyOtherTable')->find($science->getPersno());
                if($this->idm == null)
                {
                    $this->idm->setPersno($science->getPersno());
                    $this->idm->setFirstname($science->getFirstname());
                    $this->idm->setLastname($science->getLastname());
                    $this->em->persist($idm);

                }
            }
            $this->em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           $this->idm = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyOtherTable')->find($science->getPersno());
            if($this->idm == null)
            {
                $this->idm = new Users();
                $this->idm->setPersno($science->getPersno());
                $this->idm->setFirstname($science->getFirstname());
                $this->idm->setLastname($science->getLastname());
                $this->em->persist($this->idm);

            }
```

Comment: Not sure how yours code could be working, the problem is that you getting 'null'  with $this->idm = $this->em->getRepository... check if it is null and then try put setter to null variable, so I just created new object to $this->idm to use setters on that

Comment: I changed $this->idm to $idm and let it the way you code it as it is working just fine. Thank you!